# Do part of do while statement not incrementing my count of correct?

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to use a do while statement (required in this) to state the score that a person gets, however the nested if statements in my do statement seem to not be incrementing correct (i.e. it will give 0% no matter what)? What am I incorrectly writing that is not incrementing my correct variable?

Here is my code as follows

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int q1 = 2, //answer 1 correct answer
 q2 = 1, //answer 2 correct answer
 q3 = 3, //answer 3 correct answer
 correct = 0, //amount correct
 answer1, //store answer1
 answer2, //store answer2
 answer3; //store answer 3

System.out.printf("%n Question #1.) What is the capital of Iowa?"); //display question
System.out.printf("%n 1.) Iowa City \t 2.) Des Moines \t 3.) Dubuque"); //display answer
System.out.printf("%n Your answer: ");
answer1 = input.nextInt(); //input becomes initial value

while (answer1 < 1 || answer1 > 3) //while loop to check if answer is valid
{
 System.out.printf("%n Invalid Answer please enter a valid answer: "); //ask for input if not valid
 answer1 = input.nextInt();
}

switch (answer1) //switch statement for input types of answer1
{
 case 1:
  System.out.printf("%n Incorrect"); //if input 1 it is incorrect
  break; //go to next part of code

 case 2:
  System.out.printf("%n Correct"); //if input 2 it is correct
  break;

 case 3:
  System.out.printf("%n Incorrect"); //if input 3 it is incorrect
  break;
}


System.out.printf("%n Question #2.) Where is Iowa?"); //display question
System.out.printf("%n 1.) Midwest \t 2.) South \t 3.) Northeast"); //display answer
System.out.printf("%n Your answer: ");
answer2 = input.nextInt(); //input becomes initial value

while (answer2 < 1 || answer2 > 3) //make sure answer is valid
{
 System.out.printf("%n Invalid Answer please enter a valid answer: "); //ask for valid input
 answer2 = input.nextInt();
}

switch (answer2) //switch statement for chosen answers
{
 case 1:
  System.out.printf("%n Correct"); //correct if input is 1
  break;

 case 2:
  System.out.printf("%n Incorrect"); //incorrect for answer 2
  break;

 case 3:
  System.out.printf("%n Incorrect"); //incorrect for answer 3
  break;
}

System.out.printf("%n Question #3.) Who is the new president of UIowa?"); //display question
System.out.printf("%n 1.) Sally Mason \t 2.) Barack Obama \t 3.) Bruce Harreld"); //display answer
System.out.printf("%n Your answer: ");
answer3 = input.nextInt(); //input becomes initial value

while (answer3 < 1 || answer3 > 3) //make sure valid answer
{
 System.out.printf("%n Invalid Answer please enter a valid answer: "); //ask for valid answer
 answer3 = input.nextInt();
}

switch (answer3) //switch to give output depending on answer
{
 case 1:
  System.out.printf("%n Incorrect"); //if input is 1
  break;

 case 2:
  System.out.printf("%n Incorrect"); //if input is 2 this statement
  break;

 case 3:
  System.out.printf("%n Correct"); //if input is 3 this statement
  break;
}

do {
 if (answer1 == q1) {
  correct++;
 }
 if (answer2 == q2) {
  correct++;
 }
 if (answer3 == q3) {
  correct++;
 }
} while (correct <= 3);
if (correct == 3) {
 System.out.printf("%n 100%%");
} else if (correct == 2) {
 System.out.printf("%n 66.67%%");
} else if (correct == 1) {
 System.out.printf("%n 33.33%%");
} else {
 System.out.printf("%n 0%%");
}
} //end method
} //end class
```

Comment: Debugging your code with a debugger would probably have taken less time than creating this question.

Comment: The `do { ... } while (correct <= 3);` loop is your problem. Try printing out the value of `correct` when you print out the `0%` line.

Comment: The problem is that you're looping until `correct == 4`, which brings you to the `else`. But it's not clear why you're looping altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you don't actually need the do-while loop - remove it and the correct result will be displayed.

What is happening in the do-while that you keep looping until the correct variable has a value of 4 or more. (Which means if no questions were correctly answered you'd have an infinite loop.) When your logic goes to print the result, correct having a value of 4 or more means none of the if conditions are triggered, resulting in the final else executing and displaying 0%.

There are a number of other ways to simplify and improve your code - I assume you are just learning the language.